# local variable 'elevation' referenced before assignment"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, modelbuilder, qgis-3

I had got this error when I try run Qwater model.

> "2019-09-15T19:47:05     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File
>   "C:/Users/OS10/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QWater\QWaterPlugin.py",
>   line 688, in runEpanet
>                 writer = GHydraulicsInpWriter(template, self.iface)
>                 File "C:/Users/OS10/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QWater\GHydraulicsInpWriter.py",
>   line 439, in **init**
>                 self.getVirtualLines(section)
>                 File "C:/Users/OS10/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\QWater\GHydraulicsInpWriter.py",
>   line 321, in getVirtualLines
>                 length = self.getSecondVirtualLineJunction(id, elevation)
>
> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'elevation' referenced before
>   assignment"

[image]

Comment: please put the text of the error message in your question not a picture of it

Comment: It looks like a bug. Report it to the plugin author - https://github.com/jorgealmerio/QWater/issues

Comment: @user2856 I agree but it does have the error message as a picture not text

Comment: @user2856 I had report to author, thanks so much